# If we add $I$ to a matrix $M$, does that mean we always add 1 to each of $M$'s eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Title says it all, Suppose we have a matrix $\mathbf{M} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \ \text{x} \ N}$, with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, for $\ i = 1, 2 ... N$.

If we now add the identity matrix $\mathbf{I}$ to $\mathbf{M}$, are the eigenvalues of this sum $\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{M}$ *always* going to be $1 + \lambda_i$? Are there any special conditions on $\mathbf{M}$ that gaurantee this, or is this always the case?

Thanks.

Comment: $Mv = \lambda v \Leftrightarrow (I+M)v = (1 + \lambda) v$

Comment: @nik Elegant. Thank you.

Comment: @nik Seems like this would work for any scalar times $I$ too though right?

Comment: It does -- see copper.hat's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is YES! In fact:

$$\det(A+I-xI)=\det(A-(x-1)I)$$
so if $x-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $x$ is an eigenvalue of $A+I$

Comment: Interesting! Actually, now that I think of it, it can be any number in fact, not just 1 right? Like if we had $\alpha \mathbf{I}$

Comment: Yes that's right!

Comment: Shukran Sami! ;-)

Comment: haha you're welcome;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes: $M$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ **iff** $\det (\lambda I -M) = 0$ **iff** $\det( (\lambda+1)I - (M+I)) = 0 $ **iff** $M+I$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda+1$.

Under fairly general conditions, for example if $f$ is a polynomial, then if $M$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$, then the matrix $p(M)$ will have an eigenvalue $p(\lambda)$.

To see this, suppose $Mv = \lambda v$, then $p(M) v = \sum_k p_k M^k v = \sum_k p_k \lambda^k v = p(\lambda) v$.